# Uniform convergence of finite sum of functions

Tags: probability, uniform-convergence, almost-everywhere

Let $f_i:R^m \to R, i = 1,...n$ be the real functions and $\{i_k\}$ be the sequence of random variables $i_k$, which is independently randomly chosen in $\{1,...,n\}$. Denote by $f(x) =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(x)$.  Is there a constant $C$ such that $\mathbb{E}[\sup_x|\frac{1}{l}\sum_{k=1}^lf_{i_k}(x) - f(x)|] \leq \frac{C}{\sqrt{l}}$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It is used and well seen, to explain what you tried before obtaining a free homework solution ...

Comment: Hello, do you recommend a book or paper in which I can find this result?

Comment: You might want that $i_k$ is supported on $1,\dotsc,n$ and that the sequence is independently distributed. Otherwise it is clearly wrong.

Comment: Yes, this sequence is independently distributed.

Comment: @unique01 you should update your question and also add some details about your own effort.